# Prove $ \sqrt{2k}$ is irrational where $ k$ is an odd integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Question:

Prove $ \sqrt{2k}$ is irrational where $ k$ is an odd integer.

My attempt:

Proof by contradiction:

Now, assume $ \sqrt{2k}$ is rational. Then, $ \sqrt{2k} = \frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b \in Z$, $b$ not equal $0$ and $a,b$ have no common factors.

$ \sqrt{2k} = \frac{a}{b} \implies 2k = \frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}} \implies (b^{2})(2k) = a^{2} \implies 2|a^{2} \implies 2|a, \ since \ 2 \ is\  prime \implies \exists c \in Z$ such that $ a = 2c$

Then, $ (2k)(b^{2}) = a^{2} \implies (2k)(b^{2}) = 4c^{2} \implies kb^{2} = 2c^{2} \implies 2|kb^{2} \implies 2 | b^{2} \implies 2|b$, since $2$ is prime.

So,  $ 2|a$ and $ 2|b$ , a contradiction.

Comment: $\sqrt{4m+1} = \frac{a}{b} \implies 4m+2 = \frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}}$. This 2 is wrong, right?

Comment: if k is of form 2m+1; 2k is of form 4m+2 not 4m+1.

Comment: Actually, that $1$ was wrong, @ThiagoNascimento

Comment: Yes, I saw something strange, but the error is before.

Comment: Sorry it was suppose to be $ \sqrt{4m +2}$

Comment: You are assuming $a$ and $b$ are in lowest term so they can not both be even.  Prove that they both have to be even.  You already have $4m+2|a^2$ so $a$ must be even.  Let $a = 2a$ and see what happens.

Comment: @fleablood If $a = 2a$ then $ a^{2} = 4a^{2}$, which means $ 4 | a^{2}$. Then what?

Comment: 2|4m+2 so $a$ is obviously even.  So b has to be odd as a and b have no factors in common..  $b^2*(4m+2)$ is even.  Is it divisible by 4?  Should it be?

Comment: I meant $a = 2c$ (oops)  so $b^2(4m + 2) = 4c^2$.  So $b^2*(2m+1) = 2c^2$.  Is that possible.

Comment: @fleablood Please have a look at my new attempt

Comment: Almost.  The only step missing is that 2|kb^2 means 2|b^2 OR 2|k.  So just say that 2 can't divide k because k is odd.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, suppose that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime,

write $a^2=b^2(4m+2)=2b^2(2m+1)$, you deduce that $2$ divides $a^2$, and $a$, write $a=2a_1$, you have $2b^2(2m+1)=4a_1^2$, you deduce that $b^2(2m+1)=2a_1^2$. This implies that $2$ divides $b$, contradiction since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score 0):

The general result is that $\sqrt x$ is Rational iff $x$ is a perfect square. But, if we have $\sqrt {2y}$ , in order for $2y$ to be a perfect square, we must have an even number of $2$s. But this cannot happen when $y$ is odd. So $2y$ is not a perfect square and so $\sqrt {2y}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose rational, then $\sqrt{2k} = a$. We can suppose $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. We have: $2k = a^{2}$ If a is odd, $a^{2}$ too, contradction. If $a$ is even, then $a = 2m$, thus $2k = 4m^{2}$, like  this $ k = 2m^{2}$, but $k$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by contradiction: suppose that $\sqrt{2k}=\frac{n}m$ where $k,n,m\in\Bbb N_{>0}$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Then taking squares both sides we get

$$2k m^2=n^2\tag1$$

Now observe that $2km^2$ is even regardless the parity of $m$, thus $n^2$ must be even if $(1)$ holds, what imply that $n$ is even and $m$ must be odd, because $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Because $n$ is even we knows that $n^2=4j$ for some $j\in\Bbb N_{>0}$, thus we can rewrite $(1)$ as

$$km^2=2j\tag2$$

but $km^2$ is odd and $2j$ even.$\Box$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If $k$ is odd then $k^2$ is odd.  (You can prove that).

If $k$ even then $k^2$ is not only even but $4|k^2$.  (You can prove that).

And if $k$ is odd, then $2k$ is even but $4\not \mid 2k$.  (You can prove that--- and you and use $2k = 4m + 2$ to prove it.)

So you have $b^2*(4m + 2) = a^2$.   If $b$ is odd is $a$ even or odd?  Is $a^2$ divisible by $4$?  If $b$ is even is $a$ even or odd? Is it divisible by $4$?  Are any of these possible?  Is it possible for $a$ and $b$ to both be even?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

The thing inside square root has an odd power of two hence it cannot be a perfect square.